# Gnome tweaks is missing `top bar' menu option

Tags: top-bar

18.04 with gnome-flashback. The menu on the left side of Gnome Tweaks configuration tool does not have the entry 'top bar'. (Nor does it have 
'extensions' or 'workspaces'.)  How could I get these menu items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logout, then click on the little gear icon on the left of the Sign In button on login window (where you enter your password). Deselect Unity and select Ubuntu. Sign in. The menu on the left side of Gnome Tweaks configuration tool should show the entry 'top bar' again.

Comment: Thanks  you saved my day