# After installing unity ubuntu all settings are broken

Tags: unity, system-settings

After installing unity with this command

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop
```

all my settings are broken, touchpad not working, and many other things.

How to revert back?

My ubuntu version 18.04

Comment: Most likely `sudo apt purge ubuntu-unity-desktop` but you didn't provide release details (which will `sudo apt remove` plus remove configuration files used), however you may also find re-installing your prior desktop (or `dpkg-reconfigure`) maybe necessary or would achieve more.  I have no experience with it sorry, but also don't know your release so can't look up what I'd expect to happen either...

Comment: My version is 18.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Gnome tweaks is missing `top bar' menu option](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069171/gnome-tweaks-is-missing-top-bar-menu-option)

You must log out,and before login there is settings button below the editText. Choose Ubuntu